# How can I get the loop to display the initial inputs and how to accept percentages '%' as output

Tags: python

The problem is "Write a program that predicts the approximate size of a population of organisms. The application should use text boxes to allow the user to enter the starting number of organisms, the average daily population increase (as a percentage), and the number of days the organisms will be left to multiply. For example, assume the user enters the following values:

Starting number of organisms: 2

Average daily increase: 30%

Number of days to multiply: 10"

This is my code so far:

```
s = int(input("Starting number of organisms: "))
i = float(input("Average daily increase: "))
d = int(input("Number of days to multiply: "))
print("Day Approximate\tPopulation")
for d in range(s, d + 1):
    add = s * i
    s = s + add
    print(d - 1, '\t', s)
```

Output should look something like this:

```
Day Approximate Population
1               2
2               2.6
3               3.38
4               4.394
5               5.7122
6               7.42586
7               9.653619
8               12.5497
9               16.31462
10              21.209
```

This is the output from my code, the "Average daily increase" is 0.30 because I'm not sure how to put in percentage and get the code to read it as ~0.X

```
Starting number of organisms: 2
Average daily increase: 0.30
Number of days to multiply: 10
Day Approximate Population
1    2.6
2    3.38
3    4.394
4    5.7122
5    7.42586
6    9.653618
7    12.5497034
8    16.31461442
9    21.208998746000002
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I understood your question.. maybe this:

```
s = int(input("Starting number of organisms: "))
i = float(input("Average daily increase[%]: "))/100.0
d = int(input("Number of days to multiply: "))
first = True
print("Day Approximate\tPopulation")
for d in range(s, d + 1):
    if first:
        print(1, '\t', s)
        first = False
    add = s * i
    s = s + add
    print(d - 1, '\t', s)
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't really know how to word it. I guess how would I get my output to start at 1 2 and go up from there instead of 1 2.6

Comment: @ㅋㅋㅋ: Glad to hear that! In case you want that the user inputs `30%` you could try to use instead `float(input("Average daily increase[%]: ").split("%")[0])/100.0`. Remember to accept my answer if useful!

Comment: Yeah, I tried to look for something like "best answer" but I can't find it (sorry, I'm new)

Answer (score 1):

```
i = float(input("Average daily increase [%]: ")) / 100
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.format()` can help you to do that, an example from [official doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples):

```
>>> points = 19.5
>>> total = 22
>>> 'Correct answers: {:.2%}'.format(points/total)
'Correct answers: 88.64%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = float(input("Please enter starting number of organisms: "))
b = float(input("Please enter average daily increase as percentage: ")) / 100
c = [i for i in range(int(input("Please enter the number of days to multiply: ")))]
Summ = list(map(lambda x : round((a) * (1 + b) ** c.index(x), 3), c))
print("\nDays\t Approximate Population")
for i in range(len(summ)): print(i + 1, "\t", Summ[i])
```

your output will be:

```
Days     Approximate Population
1        2.0
2        2.6
3        3.38
4        4.394
5        5.712
6        7.426
7        9.654
8        12.55
9        16.315
10       21.209
```